# groovy : use variable defined in bash script outside the script

Tags: bash, groovy

Am new to groovy and am trying to get value of variable manipulated inside bash side inside groovy function.

Am having a groovy script which has multiple functions to perform some activity.

In one of the function, am calling a bash script which has some variables. 
Now outside of the shell execution, I need to use the value of the variables derived in bash script.

Bash script

```
echo -e "Performing some operations related to Azure"
var1="Value123"

export $var1
```

In my groovy file i define like below

```
def callbashAndUseVariable() {
    sh './sample.sh'

    echo "Value of variable var1"
    echo $var1
    echo "$var1"
    echo ${var1}
    sh "echo $var1"
    sh "echo \$var1"
    sh 'echo \$var1'
}
```

Tried to use value of var1 but nothing worked.

Can someone please let me know how can i achieve this. Or whatever am trying is not possible in groovy.

Comment: groovy can catch only stdout of your sh.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script
see `returnStdout` parameter

Comment: returnstdout will just print the output. that is not the requirement.
i need to get the variable value defined in shell and use in function

Comment: You can't do that. You could print to stdout several values in sh, then catch stdout from groovy and parse them.